# SugarCRM: Conditionally hide / show edit and delete button in subpanel

Tags: php, customization, sugarcrm

I have created a custom module and related it to the leads module. It has certain custom columns such as "Type", "Notes" and so on.

The "Type" column can have 2 values i.e. "Call" and "Auto".

I want to show / hide the edit and delete buttons based on the value in the Type column. What's the best way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
OcultarClass('listViewTdToolsS1');

function OcultarClass(matchClass)    {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
    for (i in elems)
        {
        if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+matchClass+" ") > -1)
            {
            elems[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider adding some comments to explain your code. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the post below

http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=69455

Comment: I've tried that out. In my case, the _displaySubPanels is never called. Do I place this code in the view.details.php of the Leads module or the custom module I created?

Comment: Placing it in the Leads module helps. But I'm still stuck at the point where I can conditionally hide / show the edit and rem buttons.